# Should be Plugman cordova plugins maintained?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

As of https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html, new plugins should be published in npm and old ones migrated to npm.

The question is, once migrated our plugins to npm, should we keep publishing plugins via `plugman publish` (update migrated ones or new plugins) besides `npm publish`? If yes, how long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cordova plugins registry has [now been made immutable](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/09/08/CPR-readonly.html) - use npm is the way forwards.